# How to Solve Problem In Post request in Phpmyadmin with flutter

Tags: php, flutter

Everything is Working Fine No Error. But I don't Know Why data is not posted on my database.

I'm new TO flutter so I need these Code Using tutorials. Get Method is Working Fine but Post method not working.
IN localhost code was working Now I hosted this project database on the server

This is my database File. Create.php

```
<?php
include "db.php";

$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$desciption = isset($_POST['desciption']) ? $_POST['desciption'] : '';
$addr = isset($_POST['addr']) ? $_POST['addr'] : '';
$image_url = isset($_POST['image_url']) ? $_POST['image_url'] : '';
$price = isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] : '';


$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO house (name, desciption,addr,image_url,price) VALUES (?, ?,?,?, ?)");
$result = $stmt->execute([$name, $desciption,$addr,$image_url,$price]);

echo json_encode($result);
```

When I'm Clicking on Submit Button on error get is this

[image: Error]

API response

[image]

I need your support. I am posting the question again because it's not been solved past 8 days

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO house (name, desciption,addr,image_url,price) VALUES (?, ?,?,?, ?)");
$result = $stmt->execute([$name, $desciption,$addr,$image_url,$price]);

in this section should also bind the parameters because you are using prepared statements.

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO house (name, desciption,addr,image_url,price) VALUES (?, ?,?,?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $name, $desciption, $addr, $image_url, $price);
    // s means string so if the price is not string you can change it to integer (i) or double (d)
    $result = $stmt->execute();
```

If this does not work please change bind_param part to:

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(2, $desciption, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $addr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $image_url, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

And you have typo in desciption, it should be "description"

Comment: please stay connected I'm trying

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in /storage/ssd3/355/18441355/public_html/create.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd3/355/18441355/public_html/create.php on line 12

Comment: can you check it as bindParam ?

Comment: You have another problem there. Can you check your file? Did you forget to add ; maybe? The code that I sent you is working probably. You have syntax error in your file.

Comment: yes i add ;  but another error                Warning: PDOStatement::bindParam() expects parameter 3 to be integer, string given in /storage/ssd3/355/18441355/public_html/create.php on line 12

Comment: <?php
include "db.php";

$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$desciption = isset($_POST['desciption']) ? $_POST['desciption'] : '';
$addr = isset($_POST['addr']) ? $_POST['addr'] : '';
$image_url = isset($_POST['image_url']) ? $_POST['image_url'] : '';
$price = isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] : 0;


$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO house (name, desciption,addr,image_url,price) VALUES (?, ?,?,?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam($name, $desciption, $addr, $image_url, $price);

$result = $stmt->execute([$name, $desciption,$addr,$image_url,$price]);

Comment: i posted code again please check i much needed this solution

Comment: You did not copy what I sent to you. bindParam statement is wrong. You should put "ssss" as your first arguement you have to tell the type of the parameter first.

    $stmt->bindParam("sssss", $name, $desciption, $addr, $image_url, $price);

Comment: ok sorry i'm adding

Comment: Can you just copy and use (without changing or editing it) the code that I sent you?

Comment: yes sir i do 
Warning: PDOStatement::bindParam() expects at most 5 parameters, 6 given in /storage/ssd3/355/18441355/public_html/create.php on line 12

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in /storage/ssd3/355/18441355/public_html/create.php on line 14

Comment: Can you try to bind parameters line by line?

$stmt->bindParam(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $desciption, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $addr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $image_url, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: sir error solved let me post the data

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct?